# Transaction issues

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, weblogic12c

What I want to do is save a user and then save a restaurant entity. I thought this will be easy but it seems that I failed to understand something.

```
    userService.save(user); //this one runs just fine
    selectedRestaurant.getEmployees().add(user);
    restaurantService.save(selectedRestaurant); //exception
```

The relation between the two is @OneToMany. No transaction annotations are used. 
I thought that the first one opens a transaction and closes it too and the second one does the same. But after trying to save the restaurant I get this:

```
    [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl  - Obtaining JDBC connection
[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl  - Obtained JDBC connection
[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  - Skipping aggressive release due to registered resources
[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl  - Mark transaction for rollback
[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  - HHH000106: Forcing container resource cleanup on transaction completion
[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - could not log warnings
java.sql.SQLException: Statement has already been closed
```

Why whould this roll back?

I'm trying to use spring data jpa (1.9.2.RELEASE), weblogic 12c, mysql 5.6.17.
If relevant Emulate Two-Phase Commit is enabled in weblogic.

Could you give me advices how to do this properly?

Comment: can you make your logs level to info and post some more log information. probably there must be an exception. post the logs around the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User id is auto generated. The save method cannot make the connection between an entity and a dto without id.